# How to position an image horizontally next to a verbatim test, both aligned by the top border?

Tags: tikz-pgf, minipage

I'm trying to position an image (decorated with a border) and a verbatim text horizontally next to each other. They must be aligned by the top border and have some space between them. I'm doing this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
  \tikz \node[draw=gray] {\includegraphics[width=2in]{foo.pdf}};
  \hspace{1em}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\linewidth}\VerbatimInput{foo.tex}\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

However, they are not aligned by the top border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to alter baselines of both elements.

A baseline if an image is at the bottom by default but `tikz` has an option to change/move either baseline of its boundary box or any of the nodes. In the example, I move the baseline to a top anchor of the only node. This is why I use an additional name `A`. Altering baeline of an image is only a partial solution.

The top alignment of a `minipage` `[t]` containing multi-lined text is set to a baseline of its first line. This is usually a case but here you would like the baseline to be set at the top edge of the `minipage`, hence `\vspace{0pt}` to an additional anchor at the top.

BTW, I couldn't compile your code with `VerbatimInput{...}`, so I commented it.

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[nopar]{kantlipsum}


\begin{document}
\tikz[baseline=(A.north)] \node (A) [draw=gray] {\includegraphics[width=2in]{example-image}};%
\hspace{1em}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.45\linewidth}%VerbatimInput{}
  \vspace{0pt}\kant[1][1]
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

---

EDIT.
Example with `yshift` added to the `baseline` (see the full code below).

Additionally, if you would like to centre the group, add an additional code

```
\begingroup
  \centering
  % tikz and the rest
  \par
\endgroup
```

Otherwise, you might want to insert `\noindent` before `\tikz`, to remove indentation, unless your document class defines paragraphs without indentations.

The full code:

```latex
\documentclass{acmart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[nopar]{kantlipsum}


\begin{document}

\begingroup     % <--- Those are required to centre the group
  \centering    % <---  
  \tikz[baseline={([yshift=-0.7\baselineskip]A.north)}]
    \node (A) [draw=gray]
    {\includegraphics[width=2in]{example-image}};%
  \hspace{1em}%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.45\linewidth}
    \kant[1][1]
  \end{minipage}
  \par          % <---
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Comment: is it possible to replace `\vspace` with something else with a similar effect? `acmart` document class complains about `\vspace` :(

Comment: Alternatively to `\vspace{0pt}`, you could shift a baseline of the image: `[baseline={([yshift=-0.7\baselineskip]A.north)}]`. I have updated my answer.

Comment: this doesn't render the same as your previous example :( The image jumps up, above the text.

Comment: I have no issue with this setup (see outcome on [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/project/634cf78731e87e2efb3b4a9d)). I provided a link to code with one more change to `\fcolorbox{}{}` and `\raisebox{}{}`. The former is another way to draw grey box and the latter changes the baseline. If this doesn't work, I am afraid you need to ask another question with code of yours, which reproduces the issue. Perhaps there is something obvious I miss.